# Windows 10, http connection stop to work (mostly)

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox

Recently I run into this wired problem a few times.
All of a sudden I can't connect to new websites, the last few sites usually work for at least a while, for instance google or Slashdot. But everything else is impossible to connect to. This includes my router AND local http server (127.0.0.1), it also affect both firefox and chrome at the same time.
Other network traffic seem to be working as it should but http/https simply gives ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED
Someone run into something similar and have some sort of workaround for it.

My best guess is that there is some windows helper for http that's been broken but I have no idea where to find it and even less on how to fix it.

Comment: Try and perform a Winsock reset. Open command prompt (cmd.exe) then type or paste: __netsh winsock reset__  Restart your system.

Comment: @vssher Thanks I will try that next time it happes.